# URL Encoding in Flex and PHP

Tags: php, apache-flex

I have got a simple flex client requesting some data from a php script. I am using URLLoader to pass the parameters to the php and wait for the response. Since the value of the parameter can contain any character, I was using escape function on the flex side to pass the value to the php script. I figured out that flex escape does not work with all the character and php's equivalent urlencode have different results on the same data.

My question is how can I safely pass a string of characters(any) to the php script. One suggestion I got was to use POST instead of GET or to base 64 encode the string but base64 itself does not contain url safe characters...e.g + gets converted to blank in php.

Comment: Did you use this [escape function](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/package.html#escape%28%29)? Which characters were not escaped properly - can you post the code?

Comment: Yes, I did use escape() function that u have mentioned. It is just a single function call like the one below

var request : URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://myserver.com/sc.php?name=" + escape(parameter));

I am then using URLLoader to send the request. I had trouble with + because it was getting converted to blank space in the php script. And escape does not even support encoding for + character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [encodeURIComponent](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/package.html#encodeURIComponent%28%29) for encoding string on a url. It will encode `+` and other characters in the variable.

> this function assumes that it is processing a URI component it treats the special separator characters (; / ? : @ & = + $ , #) as regular text that should be encoded.